# Distribution of the sum of normal random variables

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, correlation

Let $X\sim \mathcal N(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2),\ Y\sim \mathcal N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$ two normal random variables and $a,b\in \mathbb R$.

If $X,Y$ are independent, then 
$$aX+bY\sim \mathcal N(a\mu_X+b\mu_Y,a^2\sigma_X^2+b^2\sigma_Y^2)$$
If $X,Y$ are jointly normally distributed with correlation $\text{corr}(X,Y)=\rho$, then
$$aX+bY\sim \mathcal N(a\mu_X+b\mu_Y, a^2\sigma_X^2+b^2\sigma_Y^2 + 2ab\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y)$$

But what if $X,Y$ are neither independent nor jointly normally distributed, what can we say about the distribution of their sum? And what would be an example of a sum of normal random variables that is not normally distributed?

Comment: Please do not modify the question after an answer is posted, making the answer look off-topic. // Sums of normal random variables that are not normally distributed are all over the site.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your second statement is false.  This would only be true if $X,Y$ are *jointly normal*, which you do not assume. And if you're assuming joint normality then uncorrelated=independent.

Comment: Ah, I see, should I edit my question to correct the 2nd statement then? But what would be an example of $X,Y$ that are correlated with $X+Y$ not normally distributed?

Comment: The following should work.  Let $a(x)= I(|x|\leq 1) \bigl( 2 \text{sgn}(x) -1 \bigr)$ where $\text{sgn}(x)=1$ if $x>0$ and $=-1$ if $x<0$.  Then consider $f(x,y)=\phi(x)\phi(y) \bigl( 1+ a(x) a(y) \bigr)$.

Comment: Sorry, that's an example of them being uncorrelated and not normally distributed!  For correlated and not normally distributed there are many more possibilities; have a look at *copulas* if that interests you.  One standard example is the distribution with joint cdf $\Phi(x) \Phi(y) \bigl( 1- 0.5 (1-\Phi(x))(1-\Phi(y))\bigr)$, where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Regarding your first comment, what does the notation of $I$ mean? Is it the normal indicator function?

Comment: Sorry, indicator function; sets argument equal to one if true, zero if false.