# Relative entropy (divergence) of sum of two Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, information-theory, divergence-operator

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Gaussian randoms with $X \sim N(m_1, s_1)$ and $Y \sim N(m_2, s_2)$ and density functions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$. Let $f(x)$ be the density function of $X = X_1 + X_2$.

I want to derive $D(f\mathrel{\|}f_2)$. I used
$$D(X\mathrel{\|}Y) = -\int_{-∞}^∞ p(x) \ln\left( \frac{q(x)}{p(x)} \right) \,\mathrm dx,$$
but I could not describe the density functions with respect to the summation of Gaussian random variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distribution of the sum of normal random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763018/distribution-of-the-sum-of-normal-random-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent [then $f$ is the density of $N(m_1+m_2, s_1+s_2)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Independent_random_variables) (assuming $s_1$ and $s_2$ are variances?).

From here you have explicit expressions for $f$ and $f_2$ so you can compute $D(f \| f_2)$ using the formula.

Comment: Can you go to more details? because it says I should do convolution for X1 and X2.

Comment: @AliAl-Qamaji If you go to the wikipedia page I linked and scroll down, there is a proof of the claim using convolution