# Sum of normally distributed random variables is normal

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given $(X,Y)$ normal vector with:
$$
E\left(X\right)=0,\,E\left(Y\right)=0,\,Var\left(X\right)=4,\,Var\left(Y\right)=1
$$
and $Cov\left(X,Y\right)=-1$, I was asked to to calculate $f_Z(2)$ where $Z=X+2Y$. In the solution they said that:
$$
Z\sim N(E(X+2Y),Var(X+2Y))
$$
It made me think - Is it true to say that the sum of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that have normal distribution is also normal distribution? I know that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent that is true and even $X+Y\sim N(\mu_X+\mu_Y,\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2)$ but can we says the $X+Y$ is normal if we don't know that they are independent? If not, how did they got $Z\sim N(E(X+2Y),Var(X+2Y))$? If yes, is there a general formula of $X+Y\sim N(\mu_X+\mu_Y,\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2)$ or something similar?

Comment: What about $Y = -X$. Then $Z = X+Y = 0$, or you may consider $Y = f(X)$ for some easy calculated function of $X$. Then consider $\mathbb{P}(Z \le t)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distribution of the sum of normal random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763018/distribution-of-the-sum-of-normal-random-variables)

Comment: $(X,Y)$ is **jointly normal**, so any linear combination of $X$ and $Y$ is univariate normal. A google search would have answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$X\pm Y \sim N(\mu_X\pm\mu_Y; \sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2 \pm 2Cov(X,Y))$$

anyway...[you can have a look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables)

Comment: Are you sure it's $2Cov(X,Y)$ and not $4Cov(X,Y)$?

Comment: @abuka123 : You asked a general formula for the density of $X+Y$...in your particular case you have $X+2Y$ so you have to modify it  accordingly....

Comment: I mean the general formula should be $X\pm Y \sim N(\mu_X\pm\mu_Y; \sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2 \pm 4Cov(X,Y))$ no? It should be $X+2Y\sim N(0,4)$ where $X\sim N(0,4)$ and $2Y\sim N(0,4)$.

Comment: @abuka123 : no. The general formula for the denisity of $X\pm Y$ is the one I showed. You can check it also in the link I gave you.

Comment: In your case the variance of $X+2Y$ is $V(X)+4V(Y)+4cov(X,Y)$ and thus correctly $N(0;4)$